# Problem with Salesforce Site Standard Object Settings configuration

Tags: permissions, site.com, quote

We have an issue when we try configure our Site's Standard Object Permissions in production.

In our sandbox we are able to set permissions for Quote standard object, but in production, in the section Standard Object Permissions there is no object like Quote (but we have the other standard objects like Accounts, Leads, Opportunities, etc).
Do we need to enable some Salesforce feature? Unfortunately the developer who configured the sandbox does not work with us any more and we do not know if it is a standard configuration issue or something deeper.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable quote for each org.

1. From Setup, enter Quotes Settings in the Quick Find box, then select Quotes Settings.
2. Select Enable Quotes.
3. Save your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the below link to enable Quotes:

https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=quotes_enable.htm